# My Roof Air Vent

Tags: toilet

I am having a problem and I’m going crazy.. I had my kitchen remodeled and there was an air vent in the way so contractor cut it and put an mini air vent. Now when I flush the toilet it doesn’t have the strength of flow it’s sounds gurgling and air bubbles on toilet water. I don’t know what do do.

Comment: can we have a picture of the mini air vent

Answer (score 2):

Presumably "mini air vent" is meaning a **mechanical vent** (also known as **air admittance valve** or **Studor**, a brand name) And it's either improperly installed, not working correctly, or too small for the job.

What you should do its make the offending contractor fix it correctly, but this may be difficult, in which case you'll need to fix it correctly, or hire a different contractor to do so.

Exactly what's wrong with it is dificult to tell without further details. If it **ever** worked correctly it may simply need to be cleaned or replaced. If it *never* worked correctly you should have withheld the contractor's payment until it did, and the cause is likely more fundamental than a clogged valve.